# Passing an equation through a parameter into a function

Tags: python, matplotlib, oop

I am writing a program where the user enters a mathematical equation (e.g. x^2 + 2x + 2) and the function plotFunction will plot it out on a graph using matplotlib.
When I enter a parameter such as "x**2" it returns the error:
ValueError: Illegal format string "x**2"; two marker symbols

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
class Plotter:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
                
    def plotFunction(self, func):     
        x = np.arange(-100, 100)
       
        y = func
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.show()

p1 = Plotter()
p1.plotFunction("x**2")
```

Comment: First of all welcome to SO. There are quite a few things wrong here. You should work on some basics and have a look at [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) symbolic math python library. You can achieve something like what you want with this library.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly ideal, however, it is what I came up with that works right now.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
def plot_func():
    three = float(input("X ** 3:\n"))
    two = float(input("X ** 2:\n"))
    one = float(input("X:\n"))
    b = float(input("B:\n"))
    n = -10
    x = []
    y = []
    while n <= 10:
        x.append(n)
        y.append( (three * n) ** 3 + (two * n) ** 2 + (one * n) + b)
        n += 1
    return x, y

x, y = plot_func()
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I basically just broke up the different parts and it will work with any function up to x ** 3 and of course you could add more. Just make your x ** 3 equal 0 if you only have an x ** 2 function. Again, not ideal, but it will work until you can figure out something better.